# Using SBT for and libraries for the first time: lots of errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm working on my first larger project, as a newbie developer.

I found I needed an external library (junrar), so I downloaded sbt and made a simple build.sbt. But now when I try to run my program (with Intellij) I get this huge block of error messages.

```
Information:8/23/16, 8:13 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 8 warnings in 10s 420ms
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.9.1.final-52.0'
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:291)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:52)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:67)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
Warning:scalac: error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
Warning:scalac: error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
Warning:scalac: error: error while loading Arrays, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/Arrays.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 765)
Warning:scalac: error: error while loading Comparator, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/Comparator.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 20)
Warning:scalac: /var/folders/ly/9qm0nrln35ddtk1xyzmpw8n00000gn/T/sbt_d176391c/ExtractAPI.scala:479: error: java.util.Comparator does not take type parameters
Warning:scalac:   private[this] val sortClasses = new Comparator[Symbol] {
Warning:scalac:                                       ^
Warning:scalac: 5 errors found
```

build.sbt:

```
name := "CViewerMain"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.junrar" % "junrar" % "0.7"

// for debugging sbt problems
//logLevel := Level.Debug

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

Comment: What does your `build.sbt` look like? Is IntelliJ compiling your project with SBT? It looks like you're not downloading required libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought I was building with sbt, but I'm not sure. I had been just clicking the run button in the top left corner.

Comment: Unless you have the IDE plugin for IntelliJ configured, the run button is doing something else...

Comment: What plugin? I have both the Scala and SBT plugins. If not the run button, what button should I press?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that need to be in place.

On the IntelliJ side, you need to have the module being built by `SBT`. Open your 'Project Structure' and click on 'Modules'. In the middle column should be all of the modules being built. Click on your `SBT` module and, in the right side, select the `SBT` tab. If that all works, you're good to go. It should look something like this:

[image: What you're looking for.]

On the SBT configuration side, you need to make sure that [the IntelliJ plugin](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) is enabled. Normally this will be inside a `build/plugins.sbt` file. There will be a line like this:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")  // For IntelliJ
```

That *should* be all you need. If your IntelliJ is showing something different, then try re-creating your Project and specifying that it is an SBT project. When you do this point to your root level `build.sbt` file.

To confirm that your sbt file is valid, go to your command line at the root of your project and execute `sbt`. If that loads, IntelliJ should be able to take it from there. Go back to IntelliJ, open up your console and run the same thing. (Again, this should work.) Once SBT loads, execute the task to run your app. If there an error here it should be more verbose, allowing you to correct it.